# Meteor files distorted image after upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-native, meteor

Am saving images to the FilesCollection after upload images are appearing distorted or rather incomplete in the browser.[image: incomplete image]

The temp directory is showing a complete image after getting image from app but distortion happens only after saving to the database mongoDB using meteor-files

```js
let Busboy = require("busboy");
    let path = require("path"),
      os = require("os"),
      fs = require("fs");
    let tempPath;

    WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/upload", (req, res, next) => {
      var busboy = new Busboy({
        headers: req.headers
      });
      busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        tempPath = path.join("/Users/abednegotm/Desktop", path.basename(fieldname));
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempPath));
        console.log(filename);

        let size = "";
        //retrive file size
        file.on("data", data => {
          size = data.length;
        });

        fs.stat(tempPath, (_statError, _statData) => {
          const _addFileMeta = {
            fileName: filename,
            type: mimetype,
            size: size
          };
//This portion of code that save image to the collection
          fs.readFile(tempPath, (_readError, _readData) => {
            if (_readError) {
              console.log(_readError);
            } else {
              PropertyImages.write(_readData, _addFileMeta, function(
                _uploadError,
                _uploadData
              ) {
                if (_uploadError) {
                  console.log(_uploadError);
                } else {
                  console.log("Data saved to DB");
                  //unlink or remove file from temporal location after upload
                  fs.unlink(tempPath, err => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("file removed from temp");
                  }); // remove temp upload
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }); //stat
      });
      busboy.on("finish", function() {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          Connection: "close"
        });
        res.end();
      });
      return req.pipe(busboy);
    });
```

Comment: Did you check your log for errors? You have to post the code you used to upload the images so we can help you figure out what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Please provide more information, but for now I think you have a problem in back end not in react native. May be you don't convert the image well.

Comment: @JuanMendes my log has no errors i have updated my post ,@Reza i have added more information

Comment: The problem is that you are loading the image before it's fully saved, and it then caches the image, so even when it is saved fully you still get a partial image